# How to get the value of name in beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, keyerror

I am learning web scrape using BeautifulSoup.

Trying to extract the different elements from the HTML, but there is a problem when I extract data from meta tag. The list for meta is as below picture:
[image]

or slist6 pasted as below:

```
[<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>, <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>, <meta content="no-referrer" name="referrer"/>, <meta content="never" name="referrer"/>, <meta content="VPPXtECgUUeuATBacnqnCm4ydGO99reF-xgNklSbNbc" name="google-site-verification"/>, <meta content="034F16304017CA7DCF45D43850915323" name="msvalidate.01"/>, <meta content="" name="description"/>]
```

The attribute as content works in the code but doesn't work for name.  It shows Keyerror: name, The results of the codes as below picture.
May I ask for your help on how to get the name attribute?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you paste the result of `slist1.find_all('meta')` instead of attaching a screenshot of it. This would make testing easier

Comment: Thank for your suggestion,Sushil. I pasted the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking whether attribute `name` is present in element method `has_attr()` can be used:

```
for meta in slist6:
    if meta.has_attr('name'):
        print(meta['name'])
    else:
        print('not exist')
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandra! The solution works. The result is as: not exist
viewport
referrer
referrer
google-site-verification
msvalidate
description